# AngularJS: Add ng-blur event for last element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I add `onBlur` behaviour to last element in `ng-repeat`?

I tried the following hoping it I could use it like `ng-class="{classForLastItem:$last}"` but did not work:

```
<th ng-repeat="input in line.inputs">
    <input type="text" id="{{input.id}}" value="{{input.value}}" ng-blur="{addLine():$last}"/>    
</th>
```

The error in the console:

```
Syntax Error: Token '(' is unexpected, expecting [:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
ng-blur="$last && addLine()"
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was going to suggest `ng-switch-when` or something like that, but this is sooo much more elegant. Nice job!

Answer (score -1):

Ng-Blur awaits for an expression.

Try `ng-blur="addLine() == $last"`.